# Comparing two strings created from lists

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, if-statement

I want to compare two strings  from two  different from lists d1 and d2.
if the string from d1 is similar with d2, then it returns the similar strings.

here's my codes :

```
d1 = [['learn'],['car']]
d2 = [['learn'],['motor']]

str1 = ', '.join(str(i) for i in d1)
str2 = ', '.join(str(j) for j in d2)

for i in str1:
    for j in str2:
        if i == j:
            print str1, str2
```

but the output is :

```
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
['learn'], ['car'] ['learn'], ['motor']
```

I expect the output to be:

```
['learn','learn']
```

^ it comes from the similar strings in str1 and str2.

can anyone help?

Comment: Try: `print i, j`

Comment: I don't understand what you are after. Are you looking to get the intersection of the two lists? I.e, elements which occur in both lists.

Comment: It think he is.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
d1 = [['learn'],['car']]
d2 = [['learn'],['motor']]
for elem in d1:
  if elem in d2:
    print([elem[0],elem[0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach for the solution using `zip`.About [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
for i,j in zip(d1,d2):
if i==j:
    print i,j
```